# ADF 12c - Max Root View Port

Tags: oracle-adf

Can someone please explain to me what exactly "Max Root View Port" means in the context of an ADF (12c) application? I know the default value is 20, if it's not specified in adf-config.xml. I've read the Oracle documentation. However, I don't think it's clear what the actual impact of changing the setting is. I mean, the impact to end users of the application.

Is this the same concept as "max concurrent users" of the application?

Many thanks,
Brian.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not the same as "max concurrent users". And we don't care about users, but we care about sessions. And its not max session count limit either.

Root view port is basicaly main application window.
One session can have many application windows in several tabs, etc. Since this feature can be abused, number of this "tabs" restricted to some large but resonable value *(there is lower hardlimit of 5 viewports present also)*.
 Exceeding this value will cause least used viewport to expire.
 Since different users doesn't share one session, it won't limit max concurent users count.
However raising root view port limits may allow one session to consume more memory, affecting your application capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, it's max number of active application windows per session.